# POSTing JSON from a textarea has linebreaks in it, is it possible to ignore them?

Tags: html, json, textarea

I'm trying to write a simple web app that will allow me to write some JSON inside of a `textarea` element and then POST it to my server. The problem that I am facing though is that when the JSON reaches the server, it contains all of the newlines from the `textarea`. This is a problem because now I can't use JSON.parse, for example, to get it back into Javascript-land.

I have thought about just stripping newlines from it, on the server side, but is there some better way to actually send this as JSON perhaps?

Comment: can you post a sample of your JSON? JSON should be parsable regardless of whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON ignores most whitespace, **except** in the values.

Comment: Thank you. I was doing something else incorrectly and attributed the errors to the whitespace that I saw. The whitespace seems to be ignored though, so that's good.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you're doing that correctly. You either need to replace them by Javascript on your client-side, before they sent, or just doing some brush-ups after receiving on the server-side.